# Android UI Element for setting a time interval

Tags: android, time, intervals, seekbar

Hello I'm looking for a Android UI element (widget) to set a time interval, for example begin at 8:00 finish at 16:00. Something like two thumb on a single seekbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in component that does that. However, it shouldn't be too hard to implement it as your own component.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

You could probably implement it as a subclass of AbsSeekBar.

I think this one would be useful to many people (I've seen this question asked several times), so if you implement it, consider releasing it as open-source :-)